# jquery replace with wild card

Tags: javascript

at present i am using this to replace single replacement but i want to replace all stings like [timer1] [timer2] etc

```
  var final_before_message = message_before.replace("[timer]", "<b id=\"timer\"></b>");
```

it works fine but it will work only for [timer] i want to replace any occurences of words like [timer1] timer2] [timer3] upto [timer9] with       etc

for example

```
       var final_before_message = message_before.replace("[timer1]", "<b id=\"timer1\"></b>");

      var final_before_message = message_before.replace("[timer2]", "<b id=\"timer2\"></b>");

     var final_before_message = message_before.replace("[timer3]", "<b id=\"timer3\"></b>");


      var final_before_message = message_before.replace("[timer9]", "<b id=\"timer9\"></b>");
```

can i use some wildcard in replace and achieve this ?/ with one line code ??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @full-stack It's not a selector, it's just a string replacement.

Comment: `String.prototype.replace()` is a vanilla JavaScript function, nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression replacement with a capture group.

```
var final_before_message = message_before.replace(/\[timer(\d+)\]/g, '<b id="timer$1"></b>');
```

`$1` is replaced by the number that was matched by the capture group `(\d+)`.